# How to assign a single value to an entire named range VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2013, vba

I am trying to assign a single value to an entire named range.

I know this can be done by using

```
for each a in "Named Range"
    a.value = "Value"
next a
```

But is there a way it can be done in a single line of code? So that I can save runtime.

Comment: Range("Named Range").value = "Value"

Comment: Gave an Error. Error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

Comment: What does "Named Range" refer to?

Comment: As stated in two different answers, if the named range has workbook scope, you need to use workbook.Names approach. If the named range has worksheet scope, then you use sheet1.Range("myNamedRange") approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive an address of a named range with,

```
application.Names("NameOfRange").RefersToRange.Address
```

You may pass this to a variable or directly use them as a one-line code like,

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Application.names("NameOfRange").RefersToRange.Address).value = "test"
```

Comment: Following Error pops up: Error 1004:Application Defined or Object Defined error.

Comment: Well, that is strange. I will try it with other Named Ranges.

Comment: Please note that you should use this with the correct worksheet. replace `ActiveSheet` to your preference.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you state the following 'can be done':

```
for each a in "Named Range"
    a.value = "Value"
next a
```

However, this would not work as "Named Range" is a string, not a Range.

To make it a Range, it should read:

```
For Each a In Range("Named Range")
    a.Value = "Value"
Next a
```

**If that works**, then it could be replaced with:

```
Range("Named Range") = "Value"
```

**But, that shouldn't work either**, as "Named Range" is not a valid name for a range as it contains a space.

So, you've been given answers that do work, provided the named range in question is entered correctly on your sheet **and** you modify the code provided to match the name of the range.

In short the answer could be:

```
Range("A1:C3") = "Value"
```

if you want to specify the range by its address, or if using a named range:

```
Range("XXXXX") = "Value"
```

Where `XXXXX` is replaced with the name *you've* given *your* named range.

You could (and should) also qualify the sheet name for completeness;

```
Sheets("ZZZZZ").Range("XXXXX") = "Value"
```

Where `ZZZZZ` is replaced with the name of the sheet/tab, and `XXXXX` with the name of your range.

Comment: actually you don't put the " " in the name

Comment: and it runs fine. I am running the program this way. I am searching for a better way (One which does not require me to run a for loop for the entire length of the named range.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. You've provided code which does not work (you included the " " yourself) and asked how you can make it better (by removing the need to loop through each cell). Firstly, I've told you how you can make it **work** by getting your syntax right, and secondly I've told you how you can make it **better** by removing the loop and replacing your three lines with one. What more do you want?

Comment: This code gives an error. Similar to the answer above you. Actually your answer is the same as the answer above yours.

Comment: I have upvoted both the answers but not accepted any one of them. As they cant work for me. But thanks for the answer. My uvotes wont be visible as my reputation is less than 15 though.

Comment: That's why I put `So, you've been given answers that do work` in my answer. Again you're missing the point Avi. We're giving you the right answer, it would appear though that you're not tailoring the answers given to *your* scenario. I would suggest that you change your question and insert the *exact* code that you're using successfully and we'll better understand why it's not working.

Comment: Forgot to vote the answer. I realized my mistake and took the scope as current worksheet. Accepted the previous answer as it was the first.